# How to click a menu items when menu item webelements are not available

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click a menu item, however there are no webelements for the menu items.

When the menu items is not clicked the web element is shown as:

<button **aria-expanded="false"** **aria-haspopup="true**" aria-label="More actions" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="2" class="icon-only bolt-button bolt-icon-button enabled icon-only bolt-focus-treatment" data-focuszone="focuszone-226" data-is-focusable="true" id="__bolt-header-command-bar-menu-button10" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" type="button">

Once I click the menu item the Button tag changes. However the elements for the menu items are still hiddend.

[Image of the menu and after click changes in span tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDcj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on the html tag and add break on subtree modification . Then click the menu and keep pressing f8 till the drop down is visible

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, however it is still not working. Its dev.azure.com build defnitions page. Clicking F8 takes me to the source tab for infinite loops.

Comment: There is no infinite loop just keep pressing till you get what you want. Click inside the continue execution inside  console also

Comment: It finally worked with the details you have shared.. Thanks a lot.